# Can i find all points from Polyline object?

Tags: android, google-maps

i have a Polyline created with two points,

can i find all points in the Polyline ?

getPoints() method will return the points list passed in addPolyline()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SphericalUtil.interpolate()](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#interpolate-LatLng-LatLng-double-) of [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/) to get point at `fraction` (can be from `0.0` to `1.0`) part of all polylines length. For example:

```
LatLng origin = new LatLng(...);
LatLng destination = new LatLng(...);
LatLng point = SphericalUtil.interpolate(origin, destination, 0.5);
```

in `point` returns `LatLng` at half of the distance between origin position and destination.